# How to remove some filenames from the list of all filenames in that folder

Tags: file, stata, set-difference

I created in Stata a list of all files in a folder  with the following:

```
global file_all : dir "$outputsFolder" files "*.dta"
```

However, I want to remove two files from this list. I wish to create another list of files so that I can remove all the files in this new list from the file_all. I had try the following, but with no success:

```
global file_remove:  `"${outputsFolder}\dataset1.dta"' `"${outputsFolder}\dataset2.dta"'
```

And I also don't know how to create the set difference between those two lists.

Comment: The syntax you have creates a list of all `*.dta` files, not a list of all files as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
. global set A B C D E

. global subset D E

. global diff : list global set - global subset

. di "$diff"
A B C
```

I read the documentation at `help macrolists` to imply that you need extra parentheses. Nevertheless the above works.